# What is this white growth on my turtle's skin? (right forward foot)

Tags: diseases, turtles

[image]
This is my pet turtle who has lived with me for the past 13 years, She had been pretty active until last week, end of last week I noticed this white growth on her leg. What is this? Is this fungal infection?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! How does the turtle live with you? Temperature of water and air, what kind of light?

Comment: The general air temperature is usually around 21c and the water temperature around 24c, and probably hotter during afternoons. Between 12pm to 4pm, I let her bask under direct sun. When she indoors, she in an aquarium whose water level is just enough for her to swim a bit or stay at the bottom and poke her head out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a vet, so please visit or contact a vet if you have concerns about your turtle's health!

In my experience this are simple not coloured parts of skin. There are discussions what cause them, genes or environmental issues. As long as the skin looks not aflamed nor injured there is no need to worry. In my turtle the affected area spreads very slowly.

Please provide your turtle a dry and warm basking area with direct (nothing between, not even glass or similar) sunlight or a propper UV basking light bulb. This in general ensures a healthy skin and shell, killing bacteria and fungi. To dry once a day is as same important as the right amount UV rays.